# VSCode Python dynamic path for Settings python.autoComplete.extraPath

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the settings.json I can set the python.autoComplete.extraPath but currently I have to hardcode my additional paths for the project.  I know for pylint in VScode I can add these paths dynamically by executing code via the python.linting.pylintArgs with init-hook.

I was wondering if there is a way to execute code dynamically to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be to write a script to update the `settings.json` file dynamically. Not sure if the setting changes to `extraPaths` are picked up dynamically post-launch, though.

Comment: @BrettCannoon Python is able to import packages from the current directory, is there a way to add autocomplete paths the current opened script?

Comment: Python can import files from the same directory of a script is true. But that's only because when you execute a script you are telling Python that the directory the script is in is to be used as a top-level entry in `sys.path`. When you open a file in VS Code we don't' know _where_ you consider the "top" to be. If you open the directory the script is in in VS Code as your workspace then it should work.

Comment: yes, your right @BrettCannon, however I though it could be a good idea to also include current directory, but maybe could cause more problems for beginners...